# SQL - Create Unique AlphaNumeric based on a 10-digit integer stored as VARCHAR

Tags: sql, hex, varchar, alphanumeric

I'm trying to emulate a function in SQL that a client has produced in Excel.  In effect, they have a unique, 10-digit numeric value (VARCHAR) as the primary key in one of their enterprise database systems.  Within another database, they require a unique, 5-digit alphanumeric identifier.  They want that 5-digit alphanumeric value to be a representation of the 10-digit number.  So what they did in excel was to split the 10-digit number into pairs, then convert each of those pairs into a hexadecimal value, then stitch them back together.

The EXCEL equation is:

> =IF(VALUE(MID(A2,1,4))>0,DEC2HEX(VALUE(MID(A2,3,2)))&DEC2HEX(VALUE(MID(A2,5,2)))&DEC2HEX(VALUE(MID(A2,7,2)))&DEC2HEX(VALUE(MID(A2,9,2))),DEC2HEX(VALUE(MID(A2,5,2)))&DEC2HEX(VALUE(MID(A2,7,2)))&DEC2HEX((VALUE(MID(A2,9,2)))))

I need the SQL equivalent of this.  Of course, should someone out there know a better way to accomplish their goal of "a 5-digit alphanumeric identifier" based off the 10-digit number, I'm all ears.

ADDED 8/2/2011

First of all, **thank you** to everyone for the replies.  Nice to see folks willing to help and even enjoying it!  Based on all the responses, I'm apt to tell my client they're intent is sound, only their method is off kilter.  I'd also like to recommend a solution.  So the challenge remains, just modified slightly:

CHALLENGE: Within SQL, take a 10 digit, unique NUMERIC string and represent it ALPHANUMERICALLY in as few characters as possible.  The resulting string must also be unique.

Note that the first 3-4 characters in the 10-digit string are likely to be zeros, and that they could be stripped to shorten the resulting alphanumeric string.  Not required, but perhaps helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is inherently impossible. You have a 10 digit numeric value that you want to convert to a 5 digit alphanumeric value. Since there are 10 numeric characters, this means that there are 10^10 = 10 000 000 000 unique values for your 10 digit number. Since there are 36 alphanumeric characters (26 letters + 10 numbers), there are 36^5 = 60 466 176 unique values for your 5 digit number. You cannot map a set of 10 billion elements into a set with around 60 million.

Now, lets take a closer look at what your client's code is doing:

> So what they did in excel was to split the 10-digit number into pairs, then convert each of those pairs into a hexadecimal value, then stitch them back together.

This isn't 100% accurate. The excel code never uses the first 2 digits, but performs this operation on the remaining 8. There are two main problems with this algorithm which may not be intuitively obvious:

1. Two 10 digit numbers can map to the same 5 digit number. Consider the numbers 1000000117 and 1000001701. The last four digits of 1000000117 get mapped to 1 11, where the last four digits of 1000001701 get mapped to 11 1. This causes both to map to 00111.
2. The 5 digit number may not even end up being 5 digits! For example, 1000001616 gets mapped to 001010.

So, what is a possible solution? Well, if you don't care if that 5 digit number is unique or not, in MySQL you can use something like:

```
hex(<NUMERIC VALUE> % 0xFFFFF)
```

Answer (score 1):

The log of 10^10 base 2 is 33.219280948874

```
> return  math.log(10 ^ 10) / math.log(2)
33.219280948874
> = 2 ^ 33.21928
9999993422.9114
```

So, it takes 34 bits to represent this number. In hex this will take 34/4 = 8.5 characters, much more than 5.

```
> return  math.log(10 ^ 10) / math.log(16)
8.3048202372184
```

The Excel macro is ignoring the first 4 (or 6) characters of the 10 character string.

You could try encoding in [base 36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36) instead of 16. This will get you to 7 characters or less.

```
> return  math.log(10 ^ 10) / math.log(36)
6.4254860446923
```

The popular [base 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding will get you to 6 characters

```
> return  math.log(10 ^ 10) / math.log(64)
5.5365468248123
```

Even [Ascii85](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85) encoding won't get you down to 5.

```
> return  math.log(10 ^ 10) / math.log(85)
5.1829075929158
```

You need base 100 to get to 5 characters

```
> return  math.log(10 ^ 10) / math.log(100)
5
```

There aren't 100 printable ASCII characters, so this is not going to work, as zkhr explained as well, unless you're willing to go beyond ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question interesting (although I don't claim to know the answer) - I googled a bit for you out of interest and found this which may help you http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2009/05/converting-decimal-to-hexadecimal-with.html